# Hibernate Mapping issue

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I've 3 tables: A, B and C. A holds a one-to- many relation with B and B holds a one-to-one relation with C. When I do a session.save(objA), a row will be created in A, many rows will be created in B referring to the id of A and one row should be created in C for each entry in B referring to the id of B.

Now the problem is, A and B are getting populated as expected, but in C, rows are getting populated but the column containing id of B is populated with null value.

Is it the problem with the mapping given in hbm.xml?

B.hbm.xml

```
    <one-to-one name="propertyC" class="com.model.C" 
       cascade="all" fetch="join">
    </one-to-one>
```

C.hbm.xml

```
    <many-to-one name="propertyB" class="com.model.B" 
       column="B_ID"  unique ="true" fetch="join" update="true" insert="true" cascade="all">
    </many-to-one>
```

B.java

```
    class B{
    private Long id;
    private C propertyC;
    }
```

C.java

```
    class C{
    private Long id;
    private Long bId;
    private B propertyB;
    }
```

Comment: So us your current mapping please...

Comment: You need to show the relevant entity code (and if you're using xml mapping, also the mapping file)

Comment: In B.hbm.xml, <one-to-one name="propertyC" class="com.model.C" cascade="all" fetch="join"> </one-to-one> and in C.hbm.xml, <many-to-one name="propertyB" class="com.model.B" column="B_ID" unique ="true" fetch="join" update="true" insert="true" cascade="all"></many-to-one>

Comment: class B{ .. private Long B_ID; private C propertyC; ..}
class C{.. private Long C_ID; private Long bid; private B propertyB; .. }

Comment: I've modified the original query.Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a oneToOne relation beetween B and C why this is defined like a manyToOne in the C mapping (and not a **OneToOne**) ?

Furthermore, if you have a bidirectional relationship, you have to define the mappedBy element of the relationship:

```
@Entity
private static class B {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private C propertyC;
}


@Entity
class C {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Long bId;

    @OneToOne (mappedBy="propertyC")
    private B propertyB;
}
```

Comment: Hi GaetanZ, manytoOne with unique attribute set to true is equivalent to onetoone. Also, I'm using xmls to map the relations, not annotations. What would be the attribute in xml corresponding to mappedBy in annotations?

Comment: It's pretty the same: mapped-by="propertyC". I prefer the annotated version because I find it more expressive.

Comment: I agree that annotation are much more convenient, but requirements are such that we are not supposed to use it. So we have to stick to xmls :(

Comment: will try mappedBy option. Thanks GaetanZ.